# Implementing an array intersection with JSON values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array containing JSON objects such as

```
validTags = [{"tag":"tag1"}, {"tag":"tag2"}];
```

and

```
items = [{"id":123456, "tag":"tag1"}, {"id":123456, "tag":"tag2"}, {"id":7890, "tag":"tag1"}];
```

and I'm trying to figure out the id's which have both 'tags' from the first array.

E.g. the output would be:

```
[{"id":123456, "tag":"tag1 tag2"}]
```

with both the matching tags combined into one string.

Any ideas how I should be going about doing this? I was chatting to some SO users in the Javascript chatroom recently about this and they suggested an array intersection could be used, but I'm not entirely sure how I would use this to get my intended outcome with JSON :(

All answers/help appreciated!

Many Thanks

Comment: The `tag1` and `tag2` variables are strings?

Comment: Oops, yes, have edited to reflect this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using both objects and arrays:

```
validTags = [{"tag":"tag1"}, {"tag":"tag2"}];
items = [{"id":123456, "tag":"tag1"}, {"id":123456, "tag":"tag2"}, {"id":7890, "tag":"tag1"}];

accumulate = {};
// Make use of the hashing of JavaScript objects to merge the tags.
items.forEach(function(e) {
  if(accumulate[e.id] == undefined) accumulate[e.id] = [e.tag];
  else accumulate[e.id].push(e.tag);
});

// Convert the object into an array. The field 'tags' is still an array.
var result0 = [];
for(var id in accumulate) result0.push({"id": id, tags: accumulate[id]});

var result = result0.filter(
  // First we cross out those do not contain every tag.
  function(e) { return validTags.every(
    function(e1) { return e.tags.indexOf(e1.tag) != -1; }); })
  // Then we make the 'tags' array into a string.
  .map(function(e) { return {"id": e.id, "tags": e.tags.join(" ")}; });
```

Comment: Working perfectly. Comments explaining the basic steps are great too! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There are no set operations in javascript, but they are easy to define, for example:

```
intersection = function(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(x) { return b.indexOf(x) >= 0 })
}
```

For your specific task, first convert `validTags` to a list:

```
vtags = validTags.map(function(x) { return x.tag })
```

and then compute an intersection, converting each `tag` attribute in `items` into an array:

```
results = items.filter(function(x) {
    return intersection(x.tag.split(/\s+/), vtags).length == vtags.length
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var validTags = [{"tag":"tag1"}, {"tag":"tag2"}];
var items = [{"id":123456, "tag":"tag1"}, {"id":123456, "tag":"tag2"}, {"id":7890, "tag":"tag1"}]; 

var actualTags = validTags.map(function(obj){return obj.tag}),
    comparableTags = actualTags.sort().join(" ");

var tagsById = items.reduce(function(map, item) {
    if (item.id in map)
        map[item.id].push(item.tag);
    else
        map[item.id] = [ item.tag ];
    return map;
}, {});
var result = [];
for (var id in tagsById) {
    var tags = tagsById[id].sort().join(" ");
    if (comparableTags == tags) // Yai, array comparison by content!
        result.push({id: id, tag:tags});
}
return result;
```

If you were using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), you could use [`pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) instead of the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) instead of the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce); in short:

```
var comparableTags = _.pluck(validTags, "tag").sort().join(" ");
return _.chain(items).groupBy("id").map(function(id, tags) {
    return {id:id, tag:tags.sort().join(" ");
}.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.tag == comparableTags;
}).value();
```

Comment: Ah ok brill (I am using underscore :D). With the code above, if I was to have var validTags = [{"tag":"tag1"}]; would it be possible to return the items that contain tag1, even if they also contain tag2? So at the moment if it was just "tag1" in valid tags I get back ID 7890, but could I also get back ID 123456 (because it does have tag1 assigned to it)?

Comment: Then don't use my string comparison, but something like `if (_difference(actualTags, obj.tags).length == 0)` (where `obj.tags` is still an array). Not sure if there is a more expressive and performant way